# loadObjectsAtResourcePath (RestKit)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I have a method like this.

```
- (void)loadData {  

    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"];  

    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc" objectClass:[Data class] delegate:self];

}
```

I get an error that says:

> instance method '-loadObjectsAtResourcePath:objectClass:delegate' not found('return types default to 'id' ').

Can someone please help me how to call loadObjectsAtResourcePath function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the prototype that has objectMapping in it because i was trying to map the response to my own mapping called Data.
So i created an RKObjectMapping object ,configured to my own mapping class and then used this function.

```
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"];  
   [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc" objectMapping:mapping delegate:self]  ;
```

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to define the mapping manually. Then just do something like this:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] objectMappingForClass:[Data class]];
RKObjectLoader *loader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc" objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
```

Don't forget to set base resource path to your RKObjectManager singleton.

Comment: RKObjectManager manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service"];   You mean something liek this right?Which singleton are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing RestKit This sounds like a simple header problem. look at the header where "RKObjectManager" is defined. (Cmd click it in XCode to make sure it's available in your project.) Double check the method definition and make sure you're calling it correctly. Always use auto-complete to invoke methods.

Comment: It is present. Can you tell me what auto-complete is?

Comment: Auto-complete is what happens when you hit the esc key in Xcode. It automatically completes the variable name, or method name you are currently typing. This helps avoid costly typos where you feel certain your code is correct but because of a missing or extra letter it fails to work correctly.

Comment: My apologies as nomenclature can throw people. editor suggestions A.K.A. auto-complete are the first warning sign when things don't line up though I've seen them work inconsistently in Xcode. Your mileage may vary. (Or is it "your kilometerage may vary" in other countries like the UK?)

Answer (score 0):

Is your object/class implementing the  in the interface?