# Rubymotion & RestKit

Tags: object, loading, restkit, rubymotion

Has anyone gotten Rubymotion to work with RestKit's RKObjectManager and successfully loaded some objects from a server? I am having a lot of trouble with it. I have RestKit's RKClient working well. I can get and post successfully, which is great. But I can't load resources with RKObjectManager. My Rakefile looks like this:

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project'

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'RestKitTest'
  app.frameworks += %w(CoreData CFNetwork Security MobileCoreServices SystemConfiguration QuartzCore)
  app.vendor_project('vendor/RestKit', :xcode, :target => 'RestKit', :headers_dir => '../Headers/RestKit/')
end
```

my app delegate looks like this:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    @window.rootViewController = TestViewController.alloc.init
    @window.rootViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end
```

and my stub TestViewController looks like this:

```
class TestViewController < UIViewController
  def init
    super

    puts "checkpoint 1"

    manager = RKObjectManager.managerWithBaseURLString "http://mlpong.herokuapp.com"
    puts "checkpoint 2"

    mapping = RKObjectMapping.mappingForClass League.class
    puts "checkpoint 3"

    # mapping.mapAttributes("id", "name", "url", nil)
    mapping.mapKeyPath("id", toAttribute:"id")
    mapping.mapKeyPath("name", toAttribute:"name")
    mapping.mapKeyPath("url", toAttribute:"url")
    puts "checkpoint 4"

    manager.mappingProvider.setObjectMapping(mapping, forKeyPath:"")
    puts "checkpoint 5"

    manager.loadObjectsAtResourcePath("/leagues.json?auth_token=my_auth_token", delegate:self)
    puts "checkpoint 6"

    self
  end

  def objectLoader(loader, didFailWithError:error)
    puts "failed with error: #{error.domain}"
  end

  def objectLoader(loader, didLoadObjects:objects)
    puts "success!"
  end
end
```

unfortunately, you can't test with this exact code because you'd need my auth token for the site.

The **mapAttributes** method of the **RKObjectMapping** class (commented out above) won't work. If I leave it, the app outputs checkpoints 1-3 and then freaks. **rake --trace** reveals this:

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke simulator (first_time)
** Invoke build:simulator (first_time)
** Execute build:simulator
** Execute simulator
/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator "SimulateDevice" "'iPhone'"
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks":"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../OtherFrameworks" /Library/RubyMotion/bin/sim 2 1 5.1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" "./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development/RestKitTest.app"
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 3
(main)> ** Execute default
```

If I comment out the mapAttributes line, and use another (longer) version of object mapping (the 3 lines left uncommented before checkpoint 4), I get through all the checkpoints, but receive this when I **rake --trace**:

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke simulator (first_time)
** Invoke build:simulator (first_time)
** Execute build:simulator
** Execute simulator
/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator "SimulateDevice" "'iPhone'"
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks":"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../OtherFrameworks" /Library/RubyMotion/bin/sim 2 1 5.1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" "./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development/RestKitTest.app"
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 3
checkpoint 4
checkpoint 5
checkpoint 6
(main)> terminate called without an active exception** Execute default
```

I have been stuck with these errors all day. If anyone has any idea, please let me know. Help greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Pachun

Comment: Your first problem is that `mapAttributes` should be used like this: `mapping.mapAttributes(["id", "name", "url"])`. However, I still don't know how to get past the second error. (That code seems to work fine in a standard Xcode/Objective-C project, but not in a rubymotion project)

Answer (score 0):

You've called some methods that don't exist.

```
manager.mappingProvider.setObjectMapping(mapping, forKeyPath:"")
puts "checkpoint 5"

manager.loadObjectsAtResourcePath("/leagues.json?auth_token=my_auth_token", delegate:self)
puts "checkpoint 6"
```

Should be.

```
manager.loadObjectsAtResourcePath("/leagues.json?auth_token=my_auth_token", mapping:mapping, delegate:self)
puts "checkpoint 5"
```

See the similar question I found the answer on: [loadObjectsAtResourcePath (RestKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141466/loadobjectsatresourcepath-restkit)